# Classic Thesis & Microtype

Tags: microtype, classicthesis

I would to know if with classicthesis the microtype package must be loaded, or is loaded by default from `classicthesis.sty`. And if is loaded, what features are enabled?

if the microtype package must be loaded, is better this way:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,auto=true,tracking=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

or this?:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=true,expansion=true,auto=true,tracking=true}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Another thing: this is a good setting basic for microtype?

```
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,auto=true,tracking=true]{microtype}
```

Comment: Yes, `classicthesis` loads `microtype (line 232 of `classicthesis.sty` reads `\RequirePackage{microtype}`); with the option `pdfspacing`, `classicthesis` uses `expansion=false`.

Comment: ok i'm was confused if the microtype package is loaded only for the title tracking but not for the text...

Comment: @GonzaloMedina so these are the right settings basic for microtype in classicthesis and i must not add other settings of microtype?

Comment: Those are the basic options used by default, and I guess the package author considered them to be the minimum required, but you can use the options that you consider best suit your needs and won't spoil the general layout.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `classicthesis` loads `microtype` with the option `pdfspacing`. You can change the options by issuing

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{microtype}
```

before

```
\usepackage{classicthesis}
```

Comment: Short remark: `pdfspacing` is not a valid option the the package microtype.